# Flex reentrant start with user-specific state

Tags: flex-lexer

Flex sets the `YY_STATE` to `INITIAL` by default when `yyscan_t` is called.
I'm trying to make a reentrant scanner that can start with **user-specific** state instead of INITIAL.

Here is the case

```
/* comment start       //not passed into flex
   in comment          //first line passed into flex
   end of comment*/    //second line passed into flex
```

For some reasons these **2** lines are **separately** fed into the reentrant scanner and the YY_STATE the line belongs to are known. What I need is to pass the **comment state** into reentrant flex and switch `YY_STATE` to `COMMENT` before start lexing     `in comment\n`.
My workaround are adding a dummy token in head of a line and passing the state as `yyextra` into flex. Once the dummy token is recognized, switch to the specific state. Hence flex begins lexing the line with specific YY_STATE. However, adding a dummy token at the beginning of each line is time-consuming.

Here is the way I used to call reentrant flex:

```
yyscan_t scanner;                                                                                                                                                                                                                
YY_BUFFER_STATE buffer;                                                                                                                                                                                                          
yylex_init(&scanner);                                                                                                                                                                                                            
buffer = yy_scan_string(inputStr, scanner);                                                                                                                                                                                      
yyset_extra(someStructure, scanner);                                                                                                                                                                                                       
yylex(scanner);                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
yy_delete_buffer(buffer, scanner);                                                                                                                                                                                               
yylex_destroy(scanner);
```

Is it possible to set YY_STATE before `yylex(scanner)` is called ?

Comment: yylex does not reset the start condition when it is called. AFAIK, the only time the start is reset is when you create a new `yyscan_t` object. Are you doing that?

Comment: @rici, you're right. I have edited my question

Comment: Why don't you just keep on using the same `yyscan_t`? It's not sending an extra token that's slow: it's the overhead of creating and destroying scanner states. The scanner state is reusable without problems.

Comment: I agree with reuse the same `yyscan_t` will save a lot of redundant init and destroy. In this case the first  parsed line is `in comment\n` not `/* comment start\n`. Flex won't know this line is in comment unless we let it know.

Comment: How are you really calling `yylex`? Do you just call it once to lex the entire line, or do you call it for each token? And how do you save the current lexical state?

Comment: The entire line and its begin state(e.g., COMMENT) are known in this case. I call `yylex` once for each entire line.

Comment: OK, I'm not going to try any harder to extract information. I provided some sample working code which you should be able to adapt to your needs. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only calling `yylex` once for each input line, then you could just add an extra argument to `yylex` which provides the start condition to switch to, and set the start condition at the top of yylex.

But there's no simple way to refer to start conditions from outside of the flex file, nor is there a convenient way to extract the current start condition from the `yystate_t` object. The fact that you claim to have this information available suggests that you are storing it somewhere when you change start states, so you could restore the start state from that same place when you start up `yylex`. The simplest place to store the information would be the `yyextra` object, so that's the basis of this sample code:

#### File begin.int.h

```c
/* This is the internal header file, which defines the extra data structure
 * and, in this case, the tokens.
 */
#ifndef BEGIN_INT_H
#define BEGIN_INT_H

struct Extra {
  int start;
};

enum Tokens { WORD = 256 };

#endif
```

#### File begin.h

```c
/* This is the external header, which includes the header produced by
 * flex. That header cannot itself be included in the flex-generated code,
 * and it depends on the internal header. So the order of includes here is
 * (sadly) important.
 */
#ifndef BEGIN_H_
#define BEGIN_H_

#include "begin.int.h"
#include "begin.lex.h"

#endif
```

#### File: begin.l

```c
/* Very simple lexer, whose only purpose is to drop comments. */
%option noinput nounput noyywrap nodefault 8bit
%option reentrant
%option extra-type="struct Extra*"
%{
#include "begin.int.h"
/* This macro ensures that start condition changes are saved */
#define MY_BEGIN(s) BEGIN(yyextra->start = s)
%}

%x IN_COMMENT
%%
  /* See note below */
  BEGIN (yyextra->start);
"/*"          MY_BEGIN(IN_COMMENT);
[[:alnum:]]+  return WORD;
[[:space:]]+  ;
.             return yytext[0];

<IN_COMMENT>{
  "*/"        MY_BEGIN(INITIAL);
  .|[^*]+     ;
}
```

#### Note:

Any indented code after the first `%%` and before the first pattern is inserted at the beginning of `yylex`; the only thing that executes before it is the one-time initialization of the `yystate_t` object, if necessary.

#### File begin.main.c

```c
/* Simple driver which creates and destroys a scanner object for every line
 * of input. Note, however, that it reuses the extra data object, which holds
 * persistent information (in this case, the current start condition).
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include "begin.h"

int main ( int argc, char * argv[] ) {
  char* buffer = NULL;
  size_t buflen = 0;

  struct Extra my_extra = {0};

  for (;;) {
    ssize_t nr = getline(&buffer, &buflen, stdin);
    if (nr < 0) break;
    if (nr == 0) continue; 

    yyscan_t scanner;
    yylex_init_extra(&my_extra, &scanner);

    /* Ensure there are two NUL bytes for yy_scan_buffer */
    if (buflen < nr + 2) {
      buffer = realloc(buffer, nr + 2);
      buflen = nr + 2;
    }
    buffer[nr + 1] = 0;
    YY_BUFFER_STATE b = yy_scan_buffer(buffer, nr + 2, scanner);

    for (;;) {
      int token = yylex(scanner);
      if (token == 0) break;
      printf("%d: '%s'\n", token, yyget_text(scanner));
    }
    yy_delete_buffer(b, scanner);
    yylex_destroy(scanner);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

#### Build:

```sh
flex -o begin.lex.c --header-file begin.lex.h begin.l
gcc -Wall -ggdb -o begin begin.lex.c begin.main.c
```

Comment: This would be helpful. Thanks a lot!