# Lexers which require parsing information

Tags: javascript, parsing, context-free-grammar, lexer

I am currently writing a little programming language and have come across a problem. In javascript template literals, we can embed arbitrary expressions, like:

```js
let a = `hello ${ { a: 10, b: 15 } } world`
```

To properly lex the above-given snippet, the lexer needs to understand bracket matching(parsing essentially) as it can't just assume the first `}` to be the end of the embedded expression. How do lexers idiomatically solve this problem? One way is to check for proper bracket matching instead of treating them as simple operators, but I am not sure it is the best way. Looking into the code of some javascript lexers also was not very helpful.

Comment: No, the lexer does not match brackets, it just tokenises the code. And yes, that means a template literal won't lex as a single token, but really `backtick`-`"hello"`-`space`-`dollar`-`opening brace`-`space`-`opening brace`-….

Comment: That said, lexers are often generative, and a parser *can* swap out the lexer it uses to read the input stream for another one, while parsing. Template strings are one example where this might be useful, regular expression literals are another.

Comment: But that doesn't make sense, because that means something like `<backtick>{<backtick>` will be lexed as `backtick`, `opening brace`, `backtick`, when the opening brace is just a part of the string.

Comment: And if the string is lexed as tokens like identifiers and operators, then the whitespace will not be preserved, and it won't work like a string, which is definitely not the case.

Comment: Yes it will. It's the parser that is responsible to cobble these tokens together into a template string parse node.

Comment: But if `hello world` and `hello     world` are both tokenized into `hello` and `world`, how can the parser tell them separately (note that these are inside a string. outside it does not make any difference)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243855/discussion-between-rak-laptudirm-and-bergi).

Comment: Are they though? I'd think it would be the parser that'll ignore the whitespace, not the lexer. But that's on the theoretical level - in real-world parsers, the distinction is muddy, and the parser will give the lexer different directives or modes about how to find the next tokens, making this one intermingled mess.

Comment: @bergi: almost none of that describes how parsers work. And JavaScript is indeed a bit messy to parse but the basic model mostly works. Whitespace is almost never passed through to a parser; it just unnecessarily complicates the grammar

Comment: @Bergi All of the lexers which I have come across have single way communication, they just lex the tokens and the parser uses those tokens. None of them took any information back from the parser about how to lex the next tokens. I am trying to understand how that happens.

Comment: @rak: in a flex/bison parser, lexical state transitions are performed using the BEGIN macro. Since that's a macro, it can only be used inside the scanner  implementation, although it's possible to write an external interface inside the scanner file. That creates an annoying circular header dependency unless you use a push parser (my favourite solution FWIW). So most people seem to prefer triggering transitions in the lexer, because counting brackets is really not very complicated.

Comment: You can also use a scannerless parser for this sort if thing, although you might end up doing more work my advice is to try a couple of different architectures and see which one feels best for you.

Comment: @rak: in case it's useful, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62690126/1566221) outlines one way to communicate lexical state.

Comment: @rici Yes, I was not suggesting to pass whitespace from the lexer to the parser, but *if* you wanted a *pure* lexer with no back-communication, that's what you'd have to do

Answer (score 0):

The ECMAScript standard specifies (as a theoretical model) different "goal symbols" which are used in different syntactic contexts. Templated strings are one of the contexts with specific goal symbols.

That means that you need a lexical scanner which can switch states. Whether it does so itself, by duplicating part of the work of the parser, or as a result of a syntax action depends on the precise structure of the parsing architecture. You'll find implementations corresponding to both possibilities.

Putting this kind of logic into the parser is easier with predictive (top-down) parsers, such as a recursive descent parser. You could insert a call to the lexer's interface for changing states immediately after recognising the token which triggers the state change (backtick in your templated literal example). Or you could write the lexer interface so the "get a token" function also takes a lexical state argument; then your parser can maintain the lexical state. In effect, this last option is equivalent to using multiple lexical scanners, one for each state, which is also an attractive option, but it depends on separating the lexical scanner from the mechanism for reading input. (Personally, I favour this separation, but it's rarely discussed or implemented.)

Alternatively, you can use a bottom-up parser. In that case you need to be careful with synchronization between the parser's lookahead mechanism and the lexer scanner, since the interface between a bottom-up parser and a lexical scanner always allows the parser to read at least one token ahead, and it's possible that the state change needed to be done before that token was scanned. There are ways to handle this synchronization issue, but it's common for bottom-up parsers to put simple lexical state transitions into the lexer in order to avoid this issue. This necessarily involves a little duplication of effort between scanner and parser but counting braces is not so complicated.

If you're trying to use ECMAScript parsers as a source of inspiration, you need to be aware that there are many other complications with ECMAScript, particularly automatic semicolon insertion, which also involve coordination between lexer and parser. Solving those may impose other constraints on the overall architecture, and certainly makes the resulting parser code harder to read and understand.

Comment: My question is precisely that. What is the best way to switch states in the lexer?

Comment: I also should add that JavaScript is just an example here. As I mentioned, I am trying to do something similar for a different language I am trying to implement.

Comment: @rak: "what's the best way?" questions can practically never be answered in the abstract. The answer will almost always be "it depends".  As my answer indicates, one of the things it depends on is your decision about which parsing architecture to use (often a choice made on more religious than technical grounds). In the particular case of templated strings, I've used both styles and they both work fine.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what you mean by "architecture"?

Comment: @Rak: it starts with the decision about whether to use bottom-up or top-down, or variants such as PEG. Do you want to use a scannerless approach, where there's no separate lexical scanner? Or the classic architecture with separate parser and scanner components. What tools will you use to produce the component(s)? And a lot of other high-level decisions.

Comment: My original question was about the scanner, so the parser is not important here. Also, I am not using any tools to generate the lexer.

Comment: @Rak I don't think you can separate the design of the lexer from the design of the parser in this problem, since lexer<->parser intercommunication is the crux of the issue. The simple question of whether the parser calls the lexer ("pull parsing") or the lexer calls the parser ("push parsing") needs to be resolved in order to come up with an implementation. I'm not trying to be difficult, here. I just don't want to propose a detailed solution, only for you to say, "Oh, but I wanted to use recursive descent" or "Oh, but I'm writing this in Ruby." The more details you reveal, the easier it is.

Comment: I see. For your information, I am currently using a concurrently run lexer along with a recursive descent parser. The lexer is called and its token stream is provided to the parser. The parser uses those tokens to generate the ast.

Comment: @Rak: OK, I'll see what I can do. Is Python an acceptable pseudocode?

Comment: Yeah, it is....